# 301 redirect from .php to other PHP environment

Tags: php, regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I could really use some help with a 301 redirect issue in htaccess.

My challenge is that I have a lot of static .php URLs form an old website, that all has to be redirected to a new PHP base system (Magento).

So I tried with this:

```
RewriteRule (.*)\.php http://www.website.com/? [L,R=301]
```

I will do the redirects just fine, the "only" problem is, that all new URLs from the new Magento site are also redirected to the homepage (http://www.website.com/). All Magento URLs are called something.html (and not .php), by the way.

Is there any smart way to handle this, or do I have to do them all manually?

If you read all the way through this, I wish you a merry christmas. And if you have a good answer for me, then you will be my hero of the day :-)

Comment: Can you try explaining the problem again since I was unable to understand what exactly do you want.

Comment: I have url's like this:

different_texts_here.php

from the old website. The new website is based on magento (also php) which is probably why my redirect does not work.

I need to redirect all old url's where the url is containing ".php" to http://www.website.com

But how can i do that when the new system also i based on php?

Comment: Correct so you want to redirect them to `http://www.website.com/` but what problem it is causing?

Comment: Old url'er are redirectet fine, but new url's are also redirectet. So with my rule all url's are redirectet to www.website.com (so you can't even navigate on the site) :-)

Comment: Ok provided an answer below.

Comment: That does not work. The base url for the old and new site are the same.  www.website.com.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this rule in your oldsite:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \.php[\s/?] [NC]
RewriteRule !^admin http://www.newsite.com/? [L,NC,R=301]
```

Comment: That does not work. The base url for the old and new site are the same.  www.website.com.

Comment: Maybe i was a bit fast there. Now i can't log in to the admin at this url: www.website.com/admin - here i now get redirected to www.website.com. Is it possible to leave this out?

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteRule (.*)\.php($|/) http://www.website.com/? [L,R=301]
```

may also work (better) for you.